# Proof of orthogonality in the gradient descend algorithm.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, neural-networks

Ok, this is perhaps an easy question but I'm stuck, so any help will be cherished.

The gradient descent algorithm updates the weights as:

$$\textbf{w}_{t+1} = \textbf{w}_{t} - \eta\nabla E(\textbf{w}_{t}) $$

for a function $E(\textbf{w})$ to minimize.

I have read, but I can't prove it, that one of the reasons (among others) that make inefficient this algorithms is that makes a zigzag path of descent because $\nabla E(\textbf{w}_{t+1})^{T}\nabla E (\textbf{w}_{t}) = 0 $.

Why is this true?

I think if I can understand this I would understand better the classical momentum and Nesterov techniques.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on how you choose $\eta$. If it is a specified constant, then the orthogonality property is *not* true. If instead you choose $\eta$ to minimize $E(\mathbf w_{t+1})$ at each update, then orthogonality follows from the optimality condition for $E(\mathbf w_{t+1})$.

Comment: Ok, now I see:$ \frac{\partial E(\textbf{w}_{t+1})}{\partial \eta} = \frac{\partial E(\textbf{w}_{t} - \eta \nabla E(\textbf{w}_{t}))}{\partial \eta} = \frac{\partial E(\textbf{w}_{t+1})}{\partial \textbf{w}_{t+1}}\frac{\partial \textbf{w}_{t+1}}{\partial \eta} = \nabla E(\textbf{w}_{t+1})^{T}\nabla E(\textbf{w}_{t}) = 0$. Thanks.

Comment: it would be most helpful if someone could expand on the comment of David and provide a full answer? unfortunately i am not able to. but i would benefit from seeing a full solution with explanation for orthogonality and the learning rate optimization

Comment: For instance where does the negative sign go, for $ \frac{\partial w_{t+1}}{\partial\eta} = -\nabla E(w_{t}) $ ?

Comment: @user1011182: notice that $\frac{\partial E(\bf{w}_{t+1})}{\partial\eta}=0$ because we are optimizing the value of $\eta$. It's true there's a minus sign, but it disappears when passed to the other side (to the 0).